# Recursive and recursively enumerable functions.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, recursion

I am working on the following problem :

If $B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ function, then let 
$$f(B) = \{ n\in \mathbb{N} : \exists m\in B \mbox{ such } \mbox{that } f(m) = n\}$$ and 
$$f^{-1}(B) = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n)\in B\}.$$
1)Show that if $f$ is a total recursive function and $B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ recursive, then $f^{-1}(B)$ recursive.

2)Show that if $f$ is a total recursive function and $B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ recursively enumerable, then $f(B)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are recursively enumerable.

I am really struggling to come up with a proper proof for both parts.
Any ideas?

Comment: Write down the definitions of (1) $f$ is total recursive; (2) $B$ is recursive; (3) $f^{-1}(B)$ is recursive.  What do you know about function composition?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Do you mean write down here which definitions I am using for the above?

Comment: You may want to write them here as you progress in your understanding of the problem, but my suggestion was to apply the definitions to the items ($f$, $B$, ...) you are working on and see what that suggests to you.